# Error on NGINX 1.18 after installing on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, docker, nginx, webserver

I've built a docker image by installing NGINX 1.18 on Ubuntu 20.04 base os. While running, we see this error message :

> nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4

The Dockerfile looks something like this :

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 
LABEL name="nginx base image" \
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y nginx \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

I tried rebuilding the image again but that didn't solve the problem. Please suggest if anyone encountered this error and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Launch an instance of NGINX running in a container and using the default NGINX configuration with the following command:

$ docker run --name mynginx1 -p 80:80 -d nginx